# PowerBI launch issue

Tags: powerbi, launch

Whenever I try to launch Microsoft PowerBI. It takes some time to load but then a dialogue box appears that says **"Something went wrong, external component has thrown an exception"**. PowerBI that I am using is the latest on. Need help

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the program.

Comment: I reinstalled it. Still facing same issue !